# Write an array of variables to /etc/fstab using Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am using Ansible to create a distributed cluster, which requires multiple data disks and mount directories.

I am trying to complete requirement by defining the below variables, in my inventory:

```ini
[all:vars] 
minio_plate = [ { "disk_dirve": ["/dev/sdb","/dev/sdc","/dev/sdd"], "minio_data_dir": ["/minio/disk1","/minio/disk2","/minio/disk3"] } ]
```

This is my playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: 10.102.26.31
  tasks:
    - name: Mount DVD read-only
      mount:
        path: "{{item.minio_data_dir}}" 
        src: "{{item.disk_dirve}}"
        opts: defaults,noatime
        dump: "0"
        passno: "2"
        fstype: xfs
        state: present
      with_items:
        - "{{minio_plate}}"
```

Results of the task in `/etc/fstab` (reduced to the relevant part of the file):

```
['/dev/sdb',\040'/dev/sdc',\040'/dev/sdd'] ['/minio/disk1',\040'/minio/disk2',\040'/minio/disk3'] xfs defaults,noatime 0 2
```

The result I do expect would be that `/etc/fstab` contains:

```
/dev/sdb  /minio/disk1 xfs defaults,noatime 0 2 
/dev/sdc  /minio/disk2 xfs defaults,noatime 0 2 
/dev/sdd  /minio/disk3 xfs defaults,noatime 0 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two solutions here, where the first one is probably the cleanest:

1. Fix the `minio_plate` list to make it match your usage, this means, for each item, you need a dictionary containing two keys: `disk_drive` and `minio_data_dir`:

   ```ini
   [all:vars]
   minio_plate = [ { "disk_drive": "/dev/sdb", "minio_data_dir": "/minio/disk1" }, { "disk_drive": "/dev/sdc", "minio_data_dir": "/minio/disk1" }, { "disk_drive": "/dev/sdd", "minio_data_dir": "/minio/disk1" } ]
   ```

   Side note: honestly, for this type of complicated data structure, you will greatly gain in readability by writing your inventory in the YAML format:

   ```yaml
   all:
     vars:
       minio_plate:
         - disk_drive: "/dev/sdb"
           minio_data_dir: "/minio/disk1"
         - disk_drive: "/dev/sdc"
           minio_data_dir: "/minio/disk1"
         - disk_drive: "/dev/sdd"
           minio_data_dir: "/minio/disk1"
   ```
2. Fix your usage to match your data: since you have two lists, you want to loop on both of them at the same time, which could be achieve combining them with [`zip`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-and-selecting-data), first:

   ```yaml
    - name: Mount DVD read-only
      mount:
        path: "{{ item.0 }}" 
        src: "{{ item.1 }}"
        opts: defaults,noatime
        dump: "0"
        passno: "2"
        fstype: xfs
        state: present
      loop: >-
        {{ 
          minio_plate.0.minio_data_dir 
            | zip(minio_plate.0.disk_drive) 
        }}
   ```

   And even, here the fact that you have a list containing a single element under `minio_plate` makes the usage odd, to be honest.

***Important note**: in this example, I did fix the typo in `disk_drive`, that was reading `disk_dirve`*

Comment: - msg: Invalid data passed to 'loop', it requires a list, got this instead: <itertools.izip object at 0x7f037ff5abd8>. Hint: If you passed a list/dict of just one element, try adding wantlist=True to your lookup invocation or use q/query instead of lookup.       I made a mistake. Could you please check it

Comment: can you add `| list` to the variable.

Comment: You are on an old, unsupported version of Ansible, **upgrade**. Or add a `| list` filter at the end.

Comment: How do you add filters

Comment: @zccharts: `| zip(minio_plate.0.disk_drive)` become `| zip(minio_plate.0.disk_drive) | list`

Comment: Thanks it's working, but I don't understand this zip

Comment: Have you red the documentation that is linked in the answer? What exactly don't you understand in it?

Answer (score 1):

Convert the structure

```yaml
minio_plat2: |
  {% for i in minio_plate %}
  - disks:
  {% for k,v in i.disk_dirve|zip(i.minio_data_dir) %}
    - [{{ k }}, {{ v }}]
  {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
```

gives

```yaml
minio_plat2:
  - disks:
    - - /dev/sdb
      - /minio/disk1
    - - /dev/sdc
      - /minio/disk2
    - - /dev/sdd
      - /minio/disk3
```

Iterate the list with subelements

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          path: "{{ item.1.1 }}"
          src: "{{ item.1.0 }}"
          opts: defaults,noatime
          dump: "0"
          passno: "2"
          fstype: xfs
          state: present 
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ minio_plat2|from_yaml }}"
        - disks
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{}, ['/dev/sdb', '/minio/disk1']]) => 
  msg: |-
    path: "/minio/disk1"
    src: "/dev/sdb"
    opts: defaults,noatime
    dump: "0"
    passno: "2"
    fstype: xfs
    state: present
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{}, ['/dev/sdc', '/minio/disk2']]) => 
  msg: |-
    path: "/minio/disk2"
    src: "/dev/sdc"
    opts: defaults,noatime
    dump: "0"
    passno: "2"
    fstype: xfs
    state: present
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{}, ['/dev/sdd', '/minio/disk3']]) => 
  msg: |-
    path: "/minio/disk3"
    src: "/dev/sdd"
    opts: defaults,noatime
    dump: "0"
    passno: "2"
    fstype: xfs
    state: present
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    minio_plate:
      - disk_dirve: [/dev/sdb, /dev/sdc, /dev/sdd]
        minio_data_dir: [/minio/disk1, /minio/disk2, /minio/disk3]
    minio_plat2: |
      {% for i in minio_plate %}
      - disks:
      {% for k,v in i.disk_dirve|zip(i.minio_data_dir) %}
        - [{{ k }}, {{ v }}]
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}

        
  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: minio_plat2|from_yaml

    - debug:
        msg: |
          path: "{{ item.1.1 }}"
          src: "{{ item.1.0 }}"
          opts: defaults,noatime
          dump: "0"
          passno: "2"
          fstype: xfs
          state: present 
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ minio_plat2|from_yaml }}"
        - disks
```